# server for android

Tags: android, location-based

I need to implement an http server which accepts requests from android devices. To give a brief idea, this server will contain a location based game, and multiple android devices can access this game which is stored on the server. The server will also handle messages sent via mobile devices. can you give me some tips or links of articles/tutorials which might help me in this task?

Answer (score 1):

Any server can make this stuff. It depends on what programming language are you using on server-side. I don't know what language you know but I usually use ruby on rails. If you use rails, then you can use heroku for a quick and fast server to implement. But it depends on your language.

Comment: as a language I had java in mind. I once used ruby on rails about 2 years ago or so. Do you think it would be easier with ruby on rails? Because I'm not so confident in it as I only used it once. However if it isn't that much difficult, I think its worth giving it a shot. What do you think?

Comment: Then you should give a try to playframwork, it is the simplest and easiest java web framework I tried. It looks a lot like rails except it is written in java. [here](http://www.playframework.org/)

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use HTTP as a game server protocol.
Take a look at Apache Mina. It's an Java, event based framework. I recommend the "new line" protocol.